# Pivot table displaying multiple rows for some results but not others

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a fairly simple pivot table that pulls in data from a table with about 10,000 rows.  This table is a list of all transaction history over the last year, and has columns for: account name, transaction date, and a city name.  What I'm trying to do is have a table that lists one row per account, that displays the max order date (which currently works fine), and name of city (which breaks it).  For some reason, including city adds an additional row for some accounts but not others, with a different "max date".  What might cause this? All I'm trying to do is have the ability to sort by city name, to visit accounts in that area that haven't ordered in quite some time.

[image]

Comment: Check to see if you have spaces at the ends of those strings. ex.: `"Dallas"` is not the same as `"Dallas "`.

Comment: That's exactly it for the first part, thank you!  The follow up... is how do I get it to display alongside the date, so that it's all on one row?  That would make it much more useful so I can easily sort and filter..

Comment: Best way is to clean your original data.

Comment: @BigBen the cities are now cleaned up after GSD above mentioned the spaces... now it's just a layout issue for the report itself.  I was hoping to have each item all in one row, account name, the max date, and city name... but for whatever reason using the max date makes a sub/child row for the city, like the image I posted above

Comment: Do you mean you want the layout to look like what you get if you right-click in the pivot table, then *Pivot Table Options*, then under *Display*, *Classic PivotTable layout...*

Comment: @BigBen yes that's exactly it! I didn't even realize there was a classic option... thanks much